# React - Show more and search functionality

Tags: react.js, jsx

I created a rough implementation of a component that lists stuff based on data has the option to enable searching for that data. I've not used React all that much so it's probably a terrible way to implement it. I looked into passing state upwards and the most common way I saw was to do what I did and pass the setter function as a prop. One thing that isn't clean is having to pass `renderBans` as a prop but I wasn't sure how else to render each item from the given data and update the state.

The list component

```
import Ban from './Ban'
import styles from '../styles/BansList.module.css'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Search from './Search'

const BansList = ({title, bans, search=false}) => {

  const bansPerRender = 3;

  const [bansToRender, setBansToRender] = useState();
  const [next, setNext] = useState(3);

  const showMore = () => {
    setBansToRender(renderBans(bans.slice(0, next+bansPerRender)))
    setNext(next+bansPerRender)
  }

  const renderBans = bans => {
    let holdBans = []
    bans.map((ban, index) => {
      
      // convert from Unix timestamp to HH:MM:SS
      let banDate = new Date(ban.timestamp*1000)

      // if ban not expired
      if(new Date().getTime() < banDate.setMinutes(banDate.getMinutes() + ban.bantime))
        isExpired = false
        
      // reset banDate to original
      banDate = new Date(ban.timestamp * 1000)
      let permaBan;
      ban.bantime === 0 ? permaBan = true : permaBan = false; 

      holdBans.push(<Ban key={index} offenderName={ban.offender_name} offenderSteamId={ban.offender_steamid} banDate={banDate} adminName={ban.admin_name} banReason={ban.reason} banLength={ban.bantime} isExpired={false} permaBan={permaBan}/>)
    })

    return holdBans;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setBansToRender(renderBans(bans.slice(0, bansPerRender)))
  }, [])

  

  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.wrapper}>
        {search && <Search toSearch={bans} sendResults={setBansToRender} renderFunc={renderBans} resultsToSend={bansPerRender}/>}
        <h1>{title}</h1>
        {bansToRender}
        <button onClick={() => {showMore()}}>Show More</button>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default BansList;
```

The search component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import Fuse from 'fuse.js'
import SearchResults from './SearchResults'

const Search = ({toSearch, sendResults, renderFunc, resultsToSend='all'}) => {
  // setup state for search
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState();

  let isExpired = true;

  const search = (query) => {
    if(!query) {
      setSearchResults(toSearch)
      return;
    }

    const fuseGuardban = new Fuse(toSearch, {
      keys: ["offender_name", "admin_name", "offender_steamid"],
      useExtendedSearch: true
    });

    const result = fuseGuardban.search(query)
    const matches = []

    if (!result.length) {
      setSearchResults([]);
    } else {
      result.forEach(({item}) => {
        matches.push(item);
      });
      setSearchResults(matches);
    }
    if(searchResults || searchResults == [])
      sendResults(renderFunc(searchResults.slice(0, resultsToSend)))

  }

  return (
    <>

        <input type="search" placeholder="Search by name" onChange={e => search(e.target.value)}/>
        <span>{query}</span>
    </>
  )
}

export default Search;
```